# WPF How to make ColorAnimation always start from its elements current color

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm kinda new to xaml and I can't find solution for my problem.

I have a grid that is supposed to change background gradient based on its Tag value.
Change in tag value should start animation that starts from current color and ends in color according to tag value.

It works going from Tag Disabled to Enabled, from Disabled to Prohibited and from Enabled to Prohibited.

Problem rises when the tag changes in "opposite direction the triggers are written". For example when Tag changes from Prohibited to Enabled the animation starts from default color and ends in Enabled color instead of starting in Prohibited color and ending in Enabled color.

I hope my description is understandable.
Thanks in advance

```
<Grid.Style>
    <Style TargetType = "Grid"> 
        <Style.Triggers> 
            <Trigger Property = "Tag" Value = "Disabled">    
                <Trigger.EnterActions>    
                    <BeginStoryboard Name = "storyboardDisabled">     
                        <Storyboard>    
                            <ColorAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty = "Background.GradientStops[0].Color"
                                To = "{StaticResource disabled_1}" Duration = "0:0:1" />  
                            <ColorAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty = "Background.GradientStops[1].Color"
                                To = "{StaticResource disabled_2}" Duration = "0:0:1" />  
                        </Storyboard>  
                    </BeginStoryboard>  
                </Trigger.EnterActions>  
                <Trigger.ExitActions>  
                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName = "storyboardDisabled" />
                </Trigger.ExitActions>   
            </Trigger>   
            <Trigger Property = "Tag" Value = "Enabled">      
                <Trigger.EnterActions>      
                    <BeginStoryboard  Name = "storyboardEnabled">       
                        <Storyboard>       
                            <ColorAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty = "Background.GradientStops[0].Color"
                                To = "{StaticResource enabled_1}" Duration = "0:0:1" />  
                            <ColorAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty = "Background.GradientStops[1].Color"
                                To = "{StaticResource enabled_2}" Duration = "0:0:1" />  
                        </Storyboard>  
                    </BeginStoryboard>  
                </Trigger.EnterActions>  
                <Trigger.ExitActions>  
                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName = "storyboardEnabled" />   
                </Trigger.ExitActions>   
            </Trigger>   
            <Trigger Property = "Tag" Value = "Prohibited">      
                <Trigger.EnterActions>  
                    <BeginStoryboard Name = "storyboardProhibited">       
                        <Storyboard>       
                            <ColorAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty = "Background.GradientStops[0].Color"
                                To = "{StaticResource prohibited_1}" Duration = "0:0:1" />  
                            <ColorAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty = "Background.GradientStops[1].Color"
                                To = "{StaticResource prohibited_2}" Duration = "0:0:1" />  
                        </Storyboard>  
                    </BeginStoryboard>  
                </Trigger.EnterActions> 
                <Trigger.ExitActions>  
                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName = "storyboardProhibited" />   
                </Trigger.ExitActions >   
            </Trigger>   
        </Style.Triggers>   
    </Style>   
</Grid.Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I solved it in code.

```
public static void PlayButtonSwitchState(string state, MainWindow main)
        {            
            LinearGradientBrush gradientBrush = (LinearGradientBrush)main.playButton.Background;

            var stop1 = gradientBrush.GradientStops[0];
            var stop2 = gradientBrush.GradientStops[1];

            ColorAnimation gradientStop1ColorAnimation = new ColorAnimation();
            gradientStop1ColorAnimation.From = stop1.Color;
            gradientStop1ColorAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            ColorAnimation gradientStop2ColorAnimation = new ColorAnimation();
            gradientStop2ColorAnimation.From = stop2.Color;
            gradientStop2ColorAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

            if (state == "disabled")
            {
                gradientStop1ColorAnimation.To = Launcher.Resources.DisabledGradient[0];
                gradientStop2ColorAnimation.To = Launcher.Resources.DisabledGradient[1];
            }
            else if (state == "enabled")
            {
                gradientStop1ColorAnimation.To = Launcher.Resources.BlueGradient[0];
                gradientStop2ColorAnimation.To = Launcher.Resources.BlueGradient[1];
            }
            else if (state == "prohibited")
            {
                gradientStop1ColorAnimation.To = Launcher.Resources.RedGradient[0];
                gradientStop2ColorAnimation.To = Launcher.Resources.RedGradient[1];
            }

            gradientBrush.GradientStops[0].BeginAnimation(GradientStop.ColorProperty, gradientStop1ColorAnimation);
            gradientBrush.GradientStops[1].BeginAnimation(GradientStop.ColorProperty, gradientStop2ColorAnimation);
        }
```